# Loading alternate video sources with Mozilla Popcorn and sequence.js

Tags: popcornjs

Normally with html5 video you specify alternative formats so the browser an find one that it's happy with:

```
<video height="180" width="300" id="ourvideo">
  <source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.mp4">
  <source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.ogv">
  <source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.webm">
</video>
```

With sequence.js all the demos I can find only specify one format for each clip in the sequence:

http://jsfiddle.net/jmTgD/1/

http://scotland.proximity.on.ca/cadecairos/sequence/issue11/test/functional-plugin.html

essentially:

```
var sequence = Popcorn.sequence(
                "container-id",
                [
                    {
                        src: "http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/atultroll.webm",
                        in: 0,
                        out: 3
                    },
                    {
                        src: "http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/justintime.ogv",
                        in: 174,
                        out: 180
                    },
                    {
                        src: "http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.ogv",
                        in: 0,
                        out: 6
                    }
                ]);
```

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to supply alternate source with sequence.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like Popcorn.sequence will handle more than one source, but there are ways around this.

One option is to use `canPlayType` to detect which format the browser can play and then set the source accordingly. Something like this:

```
var ext = 'ogv', i, vid,
    formats = {
        'mp4': 'mp4',
        'webm': 'webm',
        'ogg': 'ogv'
    },
    files = ['atultroll', 'justintime', 'popcornplug'];

var vid = document.createElement('video');
for (i in formats) {
    if (vid.canPlayType(i)) {
        ext = formats[i];
        break;
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    files[i] += ext;
}
```

In theory, `canPlayType` is not 100% accurate, since there are variations in the actual video encode that a browser may not support, but this is not typically a problem in practice.

The other option is to use [Popcorn Splice Player](https://github.com/brianchirls/popcorn-splice). Popcorn 1.4 (not yet released, but in the master branch) allows for modules that wrap non-native players (e.g. YouTube, Vimeo) in objects that mimic HTML media elements. Splice Player is one such module that will combine multiple media sources and play them as one single video. It will support multiple sources.

```
var player = Popcorn.SplicePlayer('#container');
player.src = [
    {
        src: [ "atultroll.mp4", "atultroll.webm", "atultroll.ogv" ],
        from: 0,
        to: 3
    },
    {
        src: [ "justintime.mp4", "justintime.webm", "justintime.ogv" ],
        from: 174,
        to: 180
    },
    {
        src: [ "popcornplug.mp4", "popcornplug.webm", "popcornplug.ogv" ]",
        from: 0,
        to: 6
    }
];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply and the extra info - much appreciated! Do you know if it's possible with Sequence or Splice Player to tell it to play each clip in full rather than using 'from' and 'to'? I'm finding to play a clip in full I need to know the length of the clip in advance and only accepting integer values is causing more problems :(

Comment: Yes. With Splice player, you can just leave the from/to values out. It will figure out the duration of each clip as they load and use that to calculate the length of the whole mess. Oh, and you're welcome.

Comment: By the way, you can also specify from, but leave out to. (I really should write up some docs on this.)

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, thank you so much Brian. I'm going to switch from Sequence to Splice Player for my project.

Comment: Nice, would need that for Firefox and Chrome. Because currently I did only work on Firefox but the video won't run on Chrome even though I already I already have alternate source src mp4, ogg, and webm in HTML5. So I just need to add popcorn.splice.js in folder and where can I add/edit from above example because I don't see that in popcorn.splice.js

Comment: Should this work using youtube or vimeo as src URLs?  It doesn't seem to.