# Stitching 2 MP4 videos as one video

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, mp4, video-player

I have 2 MP4 videos, I need a flash player or a HTML5 player where I provide these 2 video URLs and they both play as a single video and not 2 separate videos.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [popcorn-splice](https://github.com/brianchirls/popcorn-splice) or [Popcorn.sequence](https://github.com/rwaldron/popcorn.sequence) as described here:

[Loading alternate video sources with Mozilla Popcorn and sequence.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916943/loading-alternate-video-sources-with-mozilla-popcorn-and-sequence-js/13501809#13501809)

Either one will play two HTML5 videos back to back. You may still need to write your own player controls. popcorn-splice has an [example](https://github.com/brianchirls/popcorn-splice/blob/master/index.html) of how to do that.